# Entity Framework and diamond joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, join

Is there any way to perform a "diamond join" with Entity Framework that doesn't involve a cross join? In SQL itself, I can say something like this:

```sql
SELECT d.*
FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.x = b.x
    LEFT JOIN c ON a.y = c.y
    LEFT JOIN d ON b.z = d.z OR c.z = d.z
WHERE a.w = 42;
```

This avoids a cross join with `d`.

For Entity Framework, the following LINQ syntax is equivalent, but performs a cross join with `d`:

```cs
from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.x equals b.x into bGroup
from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in TableC on a.y equals c.y into cGroup
from c in cGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
from d in TableD
where d.z == b.z || d.z == c.z
where a.w == 42
select d;
```

(I am making the assumption that inner joins will act the same as these left outer joins in this demonstration code; I haven't checked because the queries I'm working where this is an issue use left joins.)

Comment: Why not just use a Where.

Comment: @jdweng: That's what I'm already doing.

Comment: No! You are using from which is a join.  I'm saying eliminate the from.

Comment: I think you need to provide a proper answer instead of a comment to describe your intention.

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk if you perform hard-coded JOINS something's wrong with your model or you're trying to use the ORM for something it's not meant to do. It's the ORM's job to generate JOINS from entity relations. EF isn't a replacement for ADO.NET and LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL

Comment: In ORMs there are no tables, there are entities. If you see entities named `TableA` and `TableB` it's a strong indication something's wrong. With EF, a `Customer` would have an `Orders` property. An `Order` would have a `Product` property. If you wanted to retrieve all of a customer's ordered product you wouldn't have to join anything, just retrieve the customer object, possibly with eager loading, and just access the products through the entity properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you're missing the point. I'm expressing things in SQL because that's where the entities ultimately live, but it doesn't change the fact that diamond relationships like this are still poorly handled in both EF's mapping layer and in the LINQ syntax itself.

Comment: Also simple traversal is both inefficient due to repeated queries to the backing store, and only works if you're starting from a single source entity. What if `a.w` was itself something that many entities of A shared? Now I'd have to do that traversal for each matching element. Bad performance on the database, bad performance on the app itself.

Comment: An ORM isn't an excuse to do stupid things to the data store just because it hides it behind a pretty veneer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
(from a in TableA
join b in TableB on a.x equals b.x into bGroup
from b in bGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join c in TableC on a.y equals c.y into cGroup
from c in cGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { a = a, b = b, c = c}
).SelectMany(x => TableD.Where(y => (x.a.w == 42) && ((x.b.z == y.z) || (x.c.z == y.z))).Select(y => y))
.ToList();
```

Comment: So `CROSS APPLY` then, based on what LINQPad shows me?

Comment: What is difference between my code and a cross apply?

Comment: It's not a difference, it's that your code generates a `CROSS APPLY` in the SQL query, whereas mine generates `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: Turns out the `CROSS APPLY` generated this way actually has better timing performance than either the `CROSS JOIN` or multiple-condition `LEFT JOIN`. Not sure about the memory performance since the SQL Server profiler didn't show me that, but faster is the more important characteristic here. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: A lot of people say the WHERE is FASTER than the JOIN.